# How to get max or min values elementwise in tuples in a tuple matrix using python?

Tags: python, matrix, tuples, max, min

```
rows = int(input("Enter the Number of rows : "))
column = int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))

print("Enter the elements of First Matrix:")
matrix_a = [[tuple(map(float, input().split(" "))) for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]
print("First Matrix is: ")
for n in matrix_a:
   print(n)
print("Enter the elements of Second Matrix:")
matrix_b = [[tuple(map(float, input().split(" "))) for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]
print("second Matrix is: ")
for n in matrix_b:
   print(n)

result = [[0 for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]


for i in range(rows):
   for j in range(column):
        res = tuple(map(lambda i, j : max(i, j) , matrix_a, matrix_b))

print("Maximum of Above two Matrices is : ")
for r in res:
   print(r)
```

got the output as:

```
Enter the Number of rows : 
2
Enter the Number of Columns: 
2
Enter the elements of First Matrix:
5 6 7
3 4 5
1 2 3
7 8 9
First Matrix is: 
[(5.0, 6.0, 7.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)]
[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (7.0, 8.0, 9.0)]
Enter the elements of Second Matrix:
6 3 7
8 4 6
9 8 5
2 5 7
second Matrix is: 
[(6.0, 3.0, 7.0), (8.0, 4.0, 6.0)]
[(9.0, 8.0, 5.0), (2.0, 5.0, 7.0)]
Maximum of Above two Matrices is : 
[(6.0, 3.0, 7.0), (8.0, 4.0, 6.0)]
[(9.0, 8.0, 5.0), (2.0, 5.0, 7.0)]
```

what should I do to get (max, min, min) value in tuples of the matrix

For example if

```
matrix1 = 
[(5.0, 6.0, 7.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)]
[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (7.0, 8.0, 9.0)]

matrix2= 
[(6.0, 3.0, 7.0), (8.0, 4.0, 6.0)]
[(9.0, 8.0, 5.0), (2.0, 5.0, 7.0)]

I need the result to be 
[(6.0, 3.0, 7.0), (8.0, 4.0, 5.0)]
[(9.0, 2.0, 3.0), (7.0, 5.0, 7.0)]
```

i.e., consider the tuple1 in matrix1 (5.0, 6.0, 7.0) and tuple2 (6.0, 3.0, 7.0) in matrix2 then I want the resultant tuple to be
(max{5.0, 6.0}, min{6.0, 3.0}, min{7.0, 7.0}) =(6.0, 3.0, 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a list comprehension:

```py
result = [
    [(max(matrix_a[row][col][0], matrix_b[row][col][0]),
      *(min(a, b) for a, b in zip(matrix_a[row][col][1:], matrix_b[row][col][1:]))
      )
     for col in range(column)
     ]
    for row in range(rows)
]
print("Maximum of Above two Matrices is : ")
for r in result:
   print(r)
```

Expression

```py
max(matrix_a[row][col][0], matrix_b[row][col][0])
```

computes the max on the first component of each couple of cell at the
same position in your two matrices.

Then expression

```py
*[min(a, b) for a, b in zip(matrix_a[row][col][1:], matrix_b[row][col][1:])]
```

zips the next elements (thanks to `[1:]`) of the two cells and
produces a list containing the min elements.

The `*` operator flattens the list, which means that, at the end, the
whole expression is equivalent to:

```py
(
   max(matrix_a[row][col][0], matrix_b[row][col][0]),
   min(matrix_a[row][col][1], matrix_b[row][col][1]),
   min(matrix_a[row][col][2], matrix_b[row][col][2]),
   ...
)
```

which produces the expected result.